# Echoing span inside div with fixed width using PHP leads to span not following width

Tags: php, html, css

I have a very simple PHP script that echoes span tags inside a parent DIV.
For some reason which is something very strange, printing the spans using PHP leads the spans to not follow the div fixed width! Using an exact version but purely with HTML works well.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <?php

       echo '<div style="width:100px;">';

             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';
             echo '<span>Tumblerfacebook</span>';

       echo '</div>';

 ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's to do with using php? Try adding this css to your php version `span {display:block;}` which should make the spans take up the full div width rather than be an inline element...

Comment: yes, it has something to do with php. I have made 2 versions one PHP and one HTML. Only PHP does it! You can test the code on your server. I don't want each span on a separate line. I want them to fill the width of the DIV and then wrap. So a line can fit 2 or 3 spans or any number and then a new line

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing up, as "the spans to not follow the div fixed width" certainly doesn't make what you want clear... You probably know this already but... You'll most likely get a better answer if you provide the examples yourself, for others to help you. Goodlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try the plain HTML version, you're probably leaving the line breaks and indentation you think of as formatted code, like this:

```
<div style="width:100px;">
    <span>Tumblerfacebook</span>
    <span>Tumblerfacebook</span>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/47U5K/

Whereas the PHP script generates a single line, like this:

```
<div style="width:100px;"><span>Tumblerfacebook</span><span>Tumblerfacebook</span><!-- etc --></div>
```

It isn't specific to PHP -- if you took out the newlines and indentation in an HTML only setting, you would see the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/QtX2r/1/

The first example results in a bunch of implicit text notes being put into the line. When the browser tries to decide where to break the line for wrapping, it finds these text nodes with nothing but white space and decides it is okay to break the line there.

In the second example, the one created by PHP, there are no good spots to break the line. The browser is looking at this as one huge, continuous line, and cannot determine where to break it without breaking the word.

That's where the css property `word-wrap` comes in to play. If you tell it to `break-word`, the browser knows it can break up words to respect your outer container width.

```
<div style="width:100px; word-wrap: break-word;"><span>Tumblerfacebook</span><span>Tumblerfacebook</span><!-- etc --></div>
```

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/QtX2r/2/

Another option is to introduce spaces after each span. This gives the browser points at which it can break the line.

**Documentation**

- MDN `word-wrap` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Yup just discovered now when I viewed the source that's the spans are printed as one string...the solution is simply adding a space at the end of each echo...just tested it :)

Answer (score 2):

The way you're echoing them in PHP, there are no spaces.  This will result in no line breaks, and that will override your width.

When you did the text version, I'm sure you put spaces in without even thinking about it.